# Regex Find/Replace in Notepad++ advanced

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I'm trying to find all values and replace with following pattern :

```
<option value="">text1343 </option>

<option value="">text2yt4</option>

<option value="">text34ug</option>

<option value="">defffe</option>

<option value="">ewewe</option>
```

What do I want?

I want to copy the text between `<option value="">` AND `</option>` then paste it between `""`.

like this :

> `<option value="text1343">text1343 </option>`

How can I do a replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find: `<option value="">(.*)</option>`

Replace with: `<option value="\1">\1</option>`

Comment: Excellent
Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

find value

`value="">(.*)?(<)`

replace  with

```
value="$1">$1<
```